# Php input manipulation

Tags: php, post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            Text that needs to be processed
            <input type="text" id="text" name="t">
            <input type="submit" id ="order" name="order">
            <input type="text" name="credit" value="100" readonly="true" id="credit"/>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['order']))
            {
                print_r($_POST['t']);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I manipulate the value of "credit" on click of submit (i want to be able to set the value of the credit field to the $_POST['t] value

Comment: You mean like `value="<?php echo $_POST['t']; ?>"` ?

Comment: Are you hard set on using php because this could be easily solved with jQuery.

Comment: @735Tesla Yea Its a project and I have to use php post

Comment: So you are trying to set the value of the form to whatever the user submits?

Comment: By the way, the readonly attribute offers no security whatsoever when it comes to preventing modification, so if `credit` refers to money it wouldn't be a very good idea to use

Comment: @735Tesla I want to take in a number from the first input set a new variable that takes the value and subtracts it from the "credit" field and changes the value of "credit" to for example I enter 10 it subtracts 10 from credit being 100 = (90) and instead of displaying 100 in the field it displays the answer (90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049703/php-input-manipulation#comment38964262_25049703), this is easily achievable by doing this:

```
<input type="text" name="credit" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['order'])) ? $_POST['t'] : '100';?>" readonly="true"id="credit"/>
```

Using the shorthand ternary operator (`?:`) (<sup>*A shorter if/else*</sup>)

You're basically saying

```
echo (IF POST[order] IS SET) ? SHOW POST[t] : OTHERWISE SHOW 100;
```

<sup>*Pseudo code above*</sup>

---

**Edit:** in relation to your next [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049703/php-input-manipulation/25049767#comment38964311_25049703)

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $t = $_POST['t'];

    $v = $_POST['credit'];

    $total = ($t - $v); 
}
```

and further on (in the form)

```
<input type="text" name="credit" value="<?php echo (isset($total)) ? $total : '100';?>" readonly="true"id="credit"/>
```

<sup>*Untested Pseudo code above. You'll want to make sure that the numbers don't decrease below `0` possibly?*</sup>

---

Another edit based on your [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049703/php-input-manipulation/25049767?noredirect=1#comment38964817_25049767)

You're on the right path, you just have to set up the conditions:

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $t = $_POST['bet'];   
    $v = $_POST['credit'];

    if($_POST['bet'] > $_POST['credit']) {
        $total = $v;  
        echo "<h1>YOUR BET IS TOO HIGH MAN</h1>";
    } else {   
        $total = ($t - $v); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What If say the user enters a bet greater than the credits how do I set up an if statment such as if($_POST['bet'] > $_POST['credit']){  //set the value of credit to $_POST['credit']}else{   //set it to the value of credit - bet}

Comment: @user3491583 `if($_POST['bet'] > $_POST['credit'])` will work, what did you want to do if that was the case?

Comment: I want to alert the user that the bet is too high and the value was discarded and not change the value of credit

Comment: @user3491583 see latest edit :)

Comment: For some reason when I enter a number into bet credit doesnt change even if it passes the if

Comment: it works if i do echo $t-$v inside the if statment however it does nothing to the credits

Comment: @user3491583 You've got to print `$total` in the value of the credits text box.

Comment: <input type="text" name="credit" value="<?php echo (isset($totalCredit)) ? $totalCredit : '100'; ?>" readonly="true"id="credit"/>                                                                         if (isset($_POST['spin'])) {
                    $t = $_POST['bet'];
                    $v = $_POST['credit']; if ($t > $v) {
                        $totalCredit = $v;
                       echo $totalCredit;
               echo "<h1>YOUR BET IS TOO HIGH MAN</h1>";
                    } else {
           $totalCredit = ($v - $t);
                echo $totalCredit;
          }
       }

Comment: You want to put the `php` before you put your input :)

Comment: ok it works.  Again you were so helpful !

Comment: In theory If I were to have multiple php blocks in my code, how would I referance a variable from on to the other for example getting the value of a variable in one php block and sending it to the other